# Create a new root node with top 10 users

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, cloud, google-cloud-functions

I have the following function which ranks the users in my mobile_user table by eanred_points and assigns them a rank. This is done every time i call an http request trigger.

What i would like to accomplish is to create another root node called leaderboard which places only the top 10 users in the node.

My current function looks like this:

```
    exports.leaderboardUpdate2 = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) =>{
  var ref = admin.database().ref("/mobile_user");
    ref.orderByChild("earned_points").once("value", function(dataSnapshot) {
        var i = 0;
        dataSnapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
          var childRef = childSnapshot.ref;
          var r = (dataSnapshot.numChildren() - i);
          childRef.update({rank: r},function(error) {
              if (error != null)
                console.log("update error: " + error);
          });
          i++;
        });
    });
    res.status(200).send("Updated mobile users ranks");
});
```

How would i go and do this? Any help or advice is appreciated.

Edit: my mobile_user table structure looks like this: [image]

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably do something like this:

```
const LEADERBOARD_CUTOFF = 10;

exports.leaderboardUpdate2 = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) =>{
  const updates = [];
  const leaderboard = {};

  const ref = admin.database().ref("/mobile_user");
  const leaderboardRef = admin.database().ref("/leaderboard");

  return ref.orderByChild("earned_points").once("value")
    .then(dataSnapshot => {
      let i = 0;
      dataSnapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        const r = dataSnapshot.numChildren() - i;
        updates.push(childSnapshot.ref.update({rank: r}));
        if (r < LEADERBOARD_CUTOFF) {
          leaderboard[childSnapshot.key] = Object.assign(childSnapshot.val(), {rank: r});
        }
        i++;
      });

      updates.push(leaderboardRef.set(leaderboard)));
      return Promise.all(updates);
    }).then(() => {
      res.status(200).send("Updated mobile users ranks");
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
      res.status(500).send("Error updating ranks.");
    });
});
```

Differences from the original script:

1. Updates are aggregated into an array and the response is held until they are complete. As-is, you are likely to end up with errors as the function will clamp down on CPU / network when the HTTP response is sent and some of your updates won't go through.
2. A `leaderboard` object is created and populated appropriately as the iteration occurs. This is `set()` onto the appropriate reference as a final update in the function.
3. Promises are used throughout (they are much easier to reason about).

Comment: Thanks, i'll try to deploy the function and try an dissect it to figure out exactly how you're doing it. Athough right now i get an error on `updates.push(leaderboardRef.set(leaderboardUpdate)));` telling me that leaderboardupdate is not defined, did you mean the leaderboard object?